# Поместить в список диагонали, стоящие над главной диагональю матрицы (Python)

Tags: python, матрицы

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Помогите решить.
Дан пустой список. Поместить в него диагонали, стоящие над главной диагональю матрицы. Тоесть создать список списков.

Comment: @makskovalko, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: В чём сложности? Ясно ли как прочитать значения из диагоналей, стоящих на главной диагональю? Подсказка, чтобы прочитать `k`-ую такую диагональ: `matrix[i][i+k]`, где `i` с `0..n-k-1` включительно. Или не ясно как создать новый список для каждой диагонали, и добавить его в внешний список всех диагоналей? Задачу можно решить в одну строчку с помощью списка включения или ещё более элегантно, если используются numpy массивы.

Answer (score 1):

Создать список списков как раз не проблема.
А вот с матрицами не помогу.

## код создания словаря словарей

```
a={0:0, 1:1, 2:2}
a1={}
for i in xrange(0,10):
    a1[i]=a
```

## код создания списка списков

```
a=[0, 1, 2]
a1=[]
for i in xrange(0,10):
    a1.append(a)
```

## код создания словаря списков

```
a=[0, 1, 2]
a1={}
for i in xrange(0,10):
    a1[i]=a
```

Comment: @prospero78su, если не можете помочь, то хоть не дезинформируйте человека. Вы создаёте не список списков, а словарь словарей. Для создания пустого списка используется литерал `[]` (а не `{}`, как у вас). К тому же, вы кладёте в словарь один и тот же объект 10 раз, что может привести к неприятным сюрпризам, если один из элементов словаря понадобится изменить.

Comment: Я согласен, на счёт словаря -- исправление привёл. Список списков прилагается. Что касается сюрпризов, на сколько я понял -- автор ещё про них не знает и вопроса не задавал. )

Разве мой ответ ни разу не является помощью? )

Comment: ответ не показывает как создать 2D список, элементами которого являются диагонали (тоже списки), стоящие над главной диагональю матрицы. Посмотрите на мой комментарий выше (с подсказками).